# как переходить по редиректу который выполняет js?

Tags: python, requests

```
header = {
    'User-Agent':'',
}
    
session = requests.Session()
data = session.get(url,  headers=headers, allow_redirects=True).text
return data
```

парсер встает на странице где javascript-код который устанавливает куки и перенаправляет дальше.
Как парсить куки или дальше следовать редиректу?

Comment: Используйте Selenium